# codeigniter and inheritance: child sets parent property and then another child gets property

Tags: codeigniter, inheritance, parent, children

This is an inheritance question...mainly. Newbie here!

What I have:
2 children models of a parent model.
The two children models are exactly the same for the purpose of this question.

What I want:
Have a child model set parent model's property and have that property set for all children. If possible. So for example, Info_model sets the inherited property $this->league_id then League_model can get access to this value that was set by Info_model.
I don't know what the value of league_id is until after Ml_league_model is loaded.
What kind of work around is there to this?

My thoughts:
it seems as though when Info_model and League_model are loaded, they each have an instance of the parent model as opposed to what I want which is one instance that the children can access the properties from.

In my controller, as you can see,  the output of test() function is:

```
league id in the info_model is: 508
league id in the league_model is:
```

parent model located in /core directory

```
class Ml_league_model extends MY_Model{

    protected $league_id='';

    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

function _initialize($params = array())
{
    if (count($params) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($params as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}//end initialize
}
?>
```

a child model located in /models directory

```
class Info_model extends Ml_league_model{

function  __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_league_id(){
    echo 'league id in the info_model is: '.$this->league_id.br(1);
}
```

another child model located in /models directory

```
class League_model extends Ml_league_model{



function  __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_league_id(){
    echo 'league id in the info_model is: '.$this->league_id.br(1);
}
```

a controller located at /controllers directory

```
Class Info extends MY_Controller{


public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('Info_model');
    $this->load->model('League_model');

}

function test (){

    $this->Info_model->_initialize(array('league_id'=>508));
    $this->Info_model->get_league_id();
                $this->League_model->get_league_id();

}
```

Comment: I think you would need to use static vars instead & call them with parent::$league_id

Comment: Thanks so much @Frank!!!! I guess I need to delve deeper into oop.